# HTML5 Video Autoplay not working with fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

Okay, so I've tried pretty much everything, and something in my code is preventing the HTML5 autoplay attribute

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
-    autoplay

-    autoplay="autoplay"

-    $.fn.fullpage({
        scrollOverflow: false,
        afterRender: function(){
            $('#video')[0].play();      
        }
    });
```

Ive also tried removing part of the code in jquery.fullPage.js to see if that was making it conflict, but it just prevented me from being able to scroll.

```
/**
        * Plays video and audio elements.
        */
        function playMedia(destiny){
            var panel = getSlideOrSection(destiny);

            //playing HTML5 media elements
            panel.find('video, audio').each(function(){
                var element = $(this).get(0);

                if( element.hasAttribute('data-autoplay') && typeof element.play === 'function' ) {
                    element.play();
                }
            });

            //youtube videos
            panel.find('iframe[src*="youtube.com/embed/"]').each(function(){
                var element = $(this).get(0);

                if ( element.hasAttribute('data-autoplay') ){
                    playYoutube(element);
                }

                //in case the URL was not loaded yet. On page load we need time for the new URL (with the API string) to load.
                element.onload = function() {
                    if ( element.hasAttribute('data-autoplay') ){
                        playYoutube(element);
                    }
                };
            });
        }
```

Here's my HTML

```
<video id="video" width="100%" height="100%" class="bgvid" style="position: relative; float: left; z-index: 2; opacity: 0.4;" controls muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="images/boston.mp4" class="bgvid">



</video>

<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; float: left; margin-top: 15%; margin-left: 5%;">
    <span class="title"> Web Design and Entertainment </span><br>
    <span style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: 500; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; color: black;"> right in the heart of Boston. </span>
<br><br>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid red;">
<br>
    <span style="font-size: 19px; font-weight: 500; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; color: black;">We're a <span class="red">web design</span>, <span class="red">software engineering</span>, and <br><span class="red">entertainment</span> company to help you grow <br>your business online. </span>
<br><br><br><br>
    <a href="ourwork.html" class="workbtn">SEE&nbsp;OUR&nbsp;WORK&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Without a complete working example (and not just pieces of codes) it's really hard to help. Provide a complete **working** example (you can use jsfiddle/codepen/snippet for that).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use autoplay anymore or even use the `afterRender` callback to manually play it.

Just use `data-autoplay` as detailed in the [fullPage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#auto-playpause-embedded-media) regarding auto play  of embedded media elements.

```
<audio data-autoplay>
    <source src="http://metakoncept.hr/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

This way you can also decide if you want fullPage.js to pause it automatically on sectino/slide leave or not (by using `data-keepplaying` or not)

Answer (score 0):

the author provides a method to solve it, this work for me

```
$.fn.fullpage({
    scrollOverflow: false,
    afterRender: function(){
        $('#video')[0].play();      
    }
});
```

[here（Github fullPage issue）](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/35) is a link you can get more information for this issue